# Selected row is stuck after EntireRow.insert VBA command

Tags: vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet in which I want to insert rows between discrete ranges of data. An example sheet can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1y7tc9urghq7q5/example.xlsx?dl=0. My issue is that when I run the VBA code, a portion of one of the inserted rows always gets stuck selected and I cannot unselect it easily. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Error]

The code I am using is:

```
Sub insertrows()
For i = 1 To 2
Range("A1").Select
For j = 1 To i * 2 - 1
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Next j
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.insert
Next i
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I am using Excel for Mac 2011 (14.4.5) on a MacBook OS X 10.10.1.

Answer (score 1):

Let say that you want to insert two rows in each block of range (Correct me if im wrong)

This code will do .

```
Sub insertrows()
Dim lrow As Long
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lrow = ActiveCell.Row

Loop Until lrow = Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: I accepted this answer but now realize that it gives an 1004 error when there are only 2 blocks of data. It works fine with 3+ but not with 2. Any idea what can be fixed?

Comment: <B>on error resume next</B> - add this line at the beginning of the  sub routine

Comment: This is not very helpful since the lines are still not being added. Sure it keeps the Macro from crashing, but commands later in the Macro do not function correctly because the lines are not added. How can I avoid the error in the first place?